# Why is .xmodmap automatically executing?

Tags: startup, xubuntu, xmodmap

I'm running xubuntu 22.04. For years I have used a startup command in `Session and Startup` to remap the keyboard: `/usr/bin/xmodmap /home/xxxxx/.xmodmap`.
After performing `do-release-upgrade` to 22.04, this script is no longer necessary, the keys are automatically remapped (of course ~/.xmodmap still exists). I had to remove the startup command in order for keys to be correctly mapped.

I can't figure out why this happened. Has there been a change so that `~/.xmodmap` is automatically executed? (`man xmodmap` says "It is usually run from the user's session startup script.", I couldn't find any mention of automatic execution.)